# Heroku Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded) when I use ML models (python, django)

Tags: django, heroku, pickle, ram

I have deployed django app with ML models on heroku.

But when I use the next code in django view function for make prediction
`with open(model_path, "rb") as f:  model = pickle.load(f) pred_proba = model.predict_proba(mwp)[0] del model` 
I receive the next message:

> Process running mem=726M(141.8%)
> 2023-05-31T09:23:53.646613+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)

And if I load my ML model again the process memory increase and in the final my app crashes. I can't understand why the memory increasing occurs, because I delete my model after prediction using `del model`?

What can I do to solve this problem? Thank you.